# Should i reference Anime.SE for Lore Questions in Tag Wikis

Tags: discussion, tag-wiki

I'm looking into working on some of the Tag Wikis of games i know about as a means to try and get closer to 10k rep so i can finally start reading deleted questions and answers.

i'm wondering, here Lore Questions are kinda of a grey area and while are allowed some like them, some don't, those that don't would also down vote them (kinda unfair in my opinion).

However on Anime.SE we do allow Lore Questions on JRPGS and Visual Novels which can generate some deep lore questions and we normally refer back to Arqade if it's asking about playing the game (answers can still refer back to game mechanics such as [this one](https://anime.stackexchange.com/a/13939/1587))

So i am wondering, for tags such as [disgaea-3](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/disgaea-3) or [final-fantasy](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/final-fantasy) should i add a link pointing to Anime.SE (even to the appropriate tag if we have it) as a note to ask lore questions there?

Also this doesn't just have to apply to Japanese Games but also to games which you could ask a Lore Question on Sci-Fi.SE like [skyrim](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/skyrim) or [mass-effect](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mass-effect) though i'll probably wont touch these (which is why i ask about Anime.SE, more familiar with it)

Example for [atelier-iris-1](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/atelier-iris-1):

> For questions asking about game Plot and Universe Lore, refer to [Anime and Manga Stack Exchange](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/atelier)

Comment: See also: [How should I write Tag Wikis?](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/7837/how-should-i-write-tag-wikis)

Answer (score 3):

Lore questions are on topic so long as they are related to the game and are within reason (developer intent speculation and discussion is still off-topic). Some people don't like them, but they are on topic and have never (to my knowledge) not been so.

So should you point to other SE sites in the tag wiki for lore questions? No. It may be something that is *also* on topic on other sites, but they work perfectly well here. And personally, I don't think JRPGs and non-tie-in games should fit into the Anime & Manga SE scope at all, but maybe that's just me. Visual novels may be iffy.

If we get a question that is outside our scope, but may be in scope for another site, then we will point the asker in particular to that site (or migrate with mod approval). But a tag wiki is not the right place for that sort of info.